# ArrayList cannot resolve variable type

Tags: java, arraylist

Attempting to get a custom class known as DrawGraphics to contain an ArrayList of custom objects instead of a single Sprite.  However the ArrayList refuses to accept the new Bouncer object, and when it does, the rest of the DrawGraphics class does not recognize it.

Original Code

```
package objectssequel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class DrawGraphics {
    Bouncer movingSprite;  //this was the original single sprite

    /** Initializes this class for drawing. */
    public DrawGraphics() {
        Rectangle box = new Rectangle(15, 20, Color.RED);
        movingSprite = new Bouncer(100, 170, box);
        movingSprite.setMovementVector(3, 1);
    }

    /** Draw the contents of the window on surface. */
    public void draw(Graphics surface) {
    movingSprite.draw(surface);
    }
}
```

Attempted Solution:
First I created the ArrayList of objects of class Bouncer

```
ArrayList<Bouncer> bouncerList = new ArrayList<Bouncer>();
```

All good.  I first then inserted the following code on the line below this

```
bouncerList.add(movingSprite);
```

This generated a "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)" and "Syntax error on token "movingSprite", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token" compiler error.  I guessed this might be because I used the bouncerList.add() outside of a method body, so I created the following method for the class DrawGraphics

```
    public void addBouncer(Bouncer newBouncer) {
        bouncerList.add(newBouncer);
    }
```

I then called this method in DrawGraphics() with:

```
addBouncer(movingSprite);
```

the compiler error informed me that movingSprite could not be resolved to a variable type.  I attempted this:

```
 public void addBouncer() {
        Bouncer movingSprite;
        bouncerList.add(movingSprite);
    }
```

Then attempted to initialize movingSprite by giving it a null setting, and no such luck as well, and probably a dozen other combinations ways to fix this.  Any solutions?  How do I create an ArrayList of Bouncer objects within the DrawGraphics Class?

Edit: Is it possible to not use and remove 'Bouncer movingSprite' from the original code and create an instance of the object just from the bouncerList.add()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code

```
public void addBouncer(Bouncer newBouncer) {
        bouncerList.add(Bouncer);               // this is trying to add a class
    }
```

you need to change to

```
public void addBouncer(Bouncer newBouncer) {
    bouncerList.add(newBouncer);             // this will add the object
}
```

and after

```
  movingSprite.setMovementVector(3, 1);
```

call

```
  addBouncer (movingSprite);
```

Comment: Ahh yes that was a typo when entering my question.  I have bouncerList.add(newBouncer) in there.  Calling addBouncer(movingSprite) after the movement vector does work, however is there a different way to create the array list and add the object and remove the original 'Bouncer movingSprite' in the original code?

Comment: call `bouncerList.remove (oldBouncer)`

Comment: Poor wording on my part.  What I meant was can I create the array list objects without using the original 'Bouncer movingSprite;' code in the first place?

Comment: You can but you are using `movingSprite` in the `draw` method.  Where would that come from?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to declare and initialize the array at object construction time?  Sadly, java collections makes this seemingly obvious use case awkward.

```
List< Bouncer > bouncerList = new ArrayList< Bouncer >() { {
    add( new Bouncer() );
} };
```

This may lead to difficulty serializing your DrawGraphics class if ever that becomes necessary.  Why not populate it in the DrawGraphics constructor?

Another option:

```
List< Bouncer > bouncerList = new ArrayList< Bouncer >( Arrays.asList( new Bouncer() ) );
```

You can also use guava's Lists utility class to construct and populate an array list in a single line.